# Выбор библиотеки для проекта

Tags: c++, кроссплатформенность, поиск-библиотек

Требуется примерно определить графическу библиотеку на C++ для следующего проекта.

Приложение представляет собой полноэкранное окно, симулирующее командную строку. Соответственно, там должны присутствовать все ее функции: правила редактирования строк (допустим, нельзя редактировать вывод команд и строку логина/хоста пользователя), поддержку определенных команд, сохранение результатов сессии, подсветку команд.

Стоит заметить, что приложение должно быть кроссплатформенным (под Linux и Windows как минимум, также желательно еще и под Mac).

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: На английском SO за просьбу помочь с поиском библиотеки закидывают тапками, считается оффтопиком. А здесь получается разрешено?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, ну если даже метка создана - `[поиск-библиотек]` - что тут скажешь?..

Comment: А по теме: Как вариант, можно взять SDL2 (+ freetype для рендеринга шрифтов), но тогда каждую буковку придется рисовать отдельно. На win/mac/linux работает (даже на android/ios работает). Ее использует dosbox, например.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat А английский SO выделил для вопросов про поиск библиотек и инструментов [отдельный сайт](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: А почему не использовать для такого приложения настоящую командную строку?

Comment: @VTT, это означает, что мне придется использовать Windows API под Windows, Linux-библиотеки для Linux и непонятно что для Mac, которым вообще ни разу в жизни не пользовался.